# can we trigger a lambda function to read the user login , log out, password changed , user details event from the cognio

Tags: amazon-cognito

I would like to know how can we trigger a lambda function in cognio to read the  user events happening  in Cognio, events like user login, log out, password changed

Answer (score 0):

You have an option to set trigger in User Pool settings. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Do you have any place how they have implemented  a lambda function which clearly says about, i am new to aws

Comment: You have to create a lambda function first and then select the function in the dropdown on that screen. When lambda is triggered by these events it will recieve the event details as a parameter. You can read more about it here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-functions.html

Comment: I wanted to write a lambda function which read the events when the user activity does, like user login, log out, password change. I am new to this aws .

Comment: Yes when you create a lambda and set it to get triggered by login/logout/forgot password event, it will send you details of these events as a parameter for your lambda. You can then read those values using whatever code is applicable for your programming language. All of this is well documented in the aws docs.

Comment: type CognitoEventRequest struct {
 IdentityID     string                          `json:"identityId"`
 UserPoolID     string                          `json:"userPoolId"`
 Region         string                          `json:"region"`
 Version        string                          `json:"version"`
 Request        interface{}                     `json:"request"`
 Username       string                          `json:"userName"`
} how can i get login log out event

Comment: Inside the lambda you have to access the Context object. I'm guessing you are using NodeJS so here's the documentation for that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html

Comment: Go language iam using i am not quiet clear about the event , can you please write the way which need to retrieve the event  for example do i need to pass my function in this format  func handler(event events.CognitoEvent  events.CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup) (events.CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup, error) {

Comment: If you attach your lambda function to your login event, the function will be called as soon as someone logs in and it will get the event object as a parameter. You can then read this parameter to extract event details from it. It is well documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-programming-model-context.html
I cannot help you with code since I am a python developer.

Comment: I have created  a lambda function and attached cognito into the pre sign up section in the user. but its not invoking the lambda when i try to sign up from the UI

Comment: How do you know it's not getting triggered? Did you check the cloud front logs of the lambda?

Comment: i have figure out the issue , sorry i forgot to post. Thanks

Comment: But, according to the docs, and the image provided, there is no logout trigger event.